# Error with scripted field in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a string field, 'somekey' in my data and I am trying to generate a numeric scripted field in Kibana based on it's value. Here's what I am using :

```
doc['somekey'].value == "some-value" ? 0 : 1
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: 
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all 
shards failed; shardFailures {[lHSDLA_dRhGNHsfke75-kg][testindex][0]: 
SearchParseException[[testindex][0]: 
query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(feed_ts:[1464719400000 TO 
1467311399999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source 
[{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string
\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms
\":false}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"feed_ts\":{\"gte
\":1464719400000,\"lte\":1467311399999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"aggs\":{\"3
\":{\"histogram\":{\"field\":\"story_age\",\"interval\":1},\"aggs\":{\"4
\":{\"filters\":{\"filters\":{\"vend_position : 1\":{\"query\":{\"query_string
\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"vend_position : 
1\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":false}}}}},\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"sum\":{\"script
\":\"doc['somekey'].value == \\\"some-value\\\" ? 0 : 1\",\"lang\":\"expression
\"}}}}}}}}]]]; nested: ExpressionScriptCompilationException[Failed to parse 
expression: doc['somekey'].value == \"some-value\" ? 0 : 1]; nested: 
ParseException[ unexpected character '\"' at position (27).]; nested: 
NoViableAltException; }]"}
```

If the expression is not valid - why, are there any other means of achieving what the conditional expression above does in kibana?

Comment: Have you tried this ?`doc['somekey'].value == 'some-value' ? 0 : 1`

Comment: Yes, I got the same error

Comment: Which version of Kibana are you running?

Comment: I am using Kibana 1.7.4

Comment: You mean ES 1.7.4, but what about Kibana?

Comment: error, yes ES 1.7.4 and Kibana 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/managing-fields.html#create-scripted-field) in Kibana use the [Lucene expression scripts](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts) ever since Groovy scripts have been deemed insecure.

[Lucene expression scripts](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/expressions/index.html?org/apache/lucene/expressions/js/package-summary.html) only allow numeric expressions to be specified, which a string like `"some-value"` is not, so you'd need to actually create that other field at index time. You can also do it with an [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)